# My Thunderbird calendar contents have disappeared. How can I restore them?

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

The contents of the calendar have all disappeared, the titles are still there but no information is present. How can I get it back or is it lost for ever?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the latest Lightning add-on does not work with the version of Thunderbird that Ubuntu offers at the moment.

You can download the older version from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/versions/)